# Bright artifact where emissive flames intersect VDB. Can it be fixed?

Tags: animation, materials, volumetrics

I am animating a landing spacecraft with animated flames (procedural material) and an imported volumetric VDB for animating dust stirred up by the thrust. **Issue:** A bright artifact is created where the flames intersect the VDB.

Both the flames and VDB look great on their own, the problem being where they intersect. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks. Blender 3.6, Windows 11

[image]